# How to render custom view model within a parent layout?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, zend-framework2

I've created an SvgModel, and I'm using an SvgRenderer and SvgStrategy to output SVG+XML images with appropriate response headers.

This works fine when I simply set the SvgModel to terminate and so it only has to output the result of one view template.

However, since the first two lines of all SVG images start with the same XML, I'd like to make this a layout template into which the SvgModel used by the controller is then put in.

The problem is - when I set the SvgModel to not terminate, it is placed as a child of the default ViewModel, and so my image is wrapped in the default layout of the website.

How do I set it up so that my SvgModel (with the image template) is a child of another SvgModel (with the xml/file template)?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what're using (I'm assuming it's some external module), but just to throw it out there, you can disable a layout by calling `setTerminal(true)` on a view model in the action of a controller that gets used to display the template.

Comment: It's my own custom module and model class. setTerminal forces me to have the whole template  for each image type in one file - including common elements. I guess partials might be the way to go...